# returning an error of int has no len in python 3.8.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, data-structures

I'm facing an issue with int has no len.

Below is the code and the issue

```
def find_pair(inArr):
    outStr = -1
    for i in range(len(inArr)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(inArr)):
            if len(set(inArr[i]) | set(inArr[j])) == 6:
                if len(inArr[i] + inArr[j]) > len(outStr):
                    outStr = inArr[i] + inArr[j]
    return outStr

inArr = ["30012","250232","53201","3004355","124111"]
print(find_pair(inArr))
```

The output is below

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-6a7c01fe00b4> in <module>
      9 
     10 inArr = ["30012","250232","53201","3004355","124111"]
---> 11 print(find_pair(inArr))

<ipython-input-7-6a7c01fe00b4> in find_pair(inArr)
      4         for j in range(i+1, len(inArr)):
      5             if len(set(inArr[i]) | set(inArr[j])) == 6:
----> 6                 if len(inArr[i] + inArr[j]) > len(outStr):
      7                     outStr = inArr[i] + inArr[j]
      8     return outStr

TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

The expected output is

```
Input: ["30012","250232","53201","3004355","124111"]
Output: 300123004355
```

And

```
Input: ["01221","21313","12321"]
Output: -1
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: the minimal reproducible example of this would be  `outStr = -1; len(outStr)` ....

Comment: What did you expect the length of -1 to be?

Comment: Side note: your choice of names is not helpful. `outStr` suggests it is a string, but you initialise it as an integer, and then later expect it to have a length... It is hard to think of more confusion than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined outStr as -1 which is of type integer. I assume you want to define it as an empty string.
As a consequence you have to subtract 1 when comparing - as an empty string has a length of 0.

This modified function returns the desired values:

```
def find_pair(inArr):
    outStr = ""
    for i in range(len(inArr)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(inArr)):
            if len(set(inArr[i]) | set(inArr[j])) == 6:
                if len(inArr[i] + inArr[j]) - 1 > len(outStr):
                    outStr = inArr[i] + inArr[j]
    return outStr or -1

print(find_pair(["30012", "250232", "53201", "3004355", "124111"]))  # 300123004355
print(find_pair(["01221", "21313", "12321"]))  # -1
```

Answer (score 0):

in this line `if len(inArr[i] + inArr[j]) > len(outStr):` you try to do this `len(outStr)` when `outStr = -1` is integer 
so of course you can't measure the length of an integer and you get an error